# Pass data from observer to block

Tags: magento-1, blocks, event-observer, data

Is it possible to retrieve data from the observer and then display it on the page through custom block? 
I'm displaying some products in the home page of Magento through my custom block. I've created a custom observer which listens to the event when the product is clicked. The below code in Observer.php gets the product's data which was clicked on, for example the ID and the Name of the product. When I use Mage::log($pName) for example I can see the clicked product's Name appear in the system.log file. So that's all good. What I want to do next is get the exact same product data from this Observer file and pass it on to my block file so I could use the data in block file. For displaying the product which was clicked on in other block. Right now I have two blocks. One is responsible for all products display and the other one should only show the product which was clicked on. That's why I need to get the data to my block from the Observer.

**Observer.php**

```
public function getProductData($observer)
{
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    $pId = $product->getId();
    $pName = $product->getName();

    //Mage::log($pId);
    //Mage::log($pName);
}
```

**Block file**

```
public function recommended()
{
  //code to retrieve data from observer goes here
  //and then priting the data out 
}
```

**Phtml file**

```
<?php 
$this->recommended();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure want you (exactly) want to achieve ... but in your observer you should be able to set data to registry `Mage::register('your_identifier', $data)` and get this in your block with `$data = Mage::registry('your_identifier')`.

Maybe it helps to start with ...

**Edit:**

Observer.php

```
public function yourMethod(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    /* @var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    $product->setYourData($data);
}
```

In your block (or template file):

```
$product = Mage::registry('current_product');
$data = $product->getYourData();
```

**Edit 2:**

If you don't want to manipulate products data, you need no observer.

```
public function recommended()
{
    // this gives you the product you currently view
    $product = Mage::registry('current_product');
    return $product->getName();
}
```

Maybe it's not working, because of missing `echo`?

```
<?php echo $this->recommended(); ?>
```

Comment: I tried that. And I tried to echo the retrieved data but didn't get nothing.

Comment: Which event do you observe?

Comment: I'm observing an event "catalog_controller_product_view". What I want to do is access observer data with custom block and use that block to display the data through phtml.

Comment: I assume you want to add/manipulate data for the product? See edited answer ... (Magento1?)

Comment: I edited the question and added my Observer.php file. Right now I can use these variables like $pName and it's value inside this observer file. I need to get these values passed on to my block file so I could use them to display the value of $pName on the page for example. Yes I'm using Magento 1.x.

Comment: If you are on "Product View Page" you can use `$product = Mage::registry('current_product');` as written above -or i'm not getting your question right ;)

Comment: I edited the whole question. I hope it makes things a bit more clear.

Comment: Can you please post the rest of your code (block/phtml)? I (think I) understand what you want to achieve ... but i'm not sure what's wrong with `Mage::registry(...)`

Comment: Added block and phtml file. But I don't have anything there yet. I tried using the registry option. Wrote ""Mage::register('your_identifier', $data)"" in the Observer file and tried to get the data in the block file by ""$data = Mage::registry('your_identifier')"".

Comment: The registry option works within the Observer file. When I set the data to registry and access it right after under different assigned variable. But when I try to access it from the block file it's not working. Returning null.

Comment: Updated answer again.

Comment: I still need the observer and the data from it. Because yes, right now I only want to display the product that was clicked on. And I want to display/change every time a different product is clicked. So If something else is clicked then something else is displayed as well. But the reason why I have to get this basic thing working is that later on I have to connect this observer with the API and furthermore the API gives back some data and then I would have to use the observer anyway/get the data from there.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the recommended function being called before anything could have received from the observer.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are instantiating your block you could also get the block in your observer and use the `_data` methods of getting/setting its data. If you are calling `createBlock` in a template or block this will not work, but if you are defining your block in layout this should work just fine.

```
public function getProductData($observer)
{
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    $pId = $product->getId();
    $pName = $product->getName();
    $block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('<your_block_name_here>');
    if($block)
    {
        $block->setProductId($pId);
        $block->setProductName($pName);
    }

    //Mage::log($pId);
    //Mage::log($pName);
}
```

Then in your block:

```
public function recommended()
{
    $pId = $this->getProductId();
    $pName = $this->getProductName();
}
```

This works because the layout object caches each block it creates in a `_blocks` property which is keyed by the block name, so when it goes to generate the block from `toHtml` it will get the same instance you just set those properties on.